# how do I change a task priority in simulink

Tags: simulink

It appears Simulink uses Rate monotonic scheduling and assigns task priorities based on sample rates. Is there a way to manually set a higher rate task to lower priority than a lower rate task within a set of periodic tasks?

I want to change the priority of my actual threads on the target OS so that a lower frequency thread is higher priority than a higher frequency thread. I think the block order is just a static ordering within each thread. It looks like by default it makes higher frequency threads higher priority. Priority gets assigned based on ordering of frequencies in an array in ertposixthread.tlc so I think I need to change the thread frequency ordering in the model if that is possible.

Comment: This may be possible by manually editing the generated code, but it is not possible from Simulink itself.  There is a check made that faster tasks have a higher priority and there's no way around that.  (I'm curious as to why you'd want a faster task to have a lower priority anyway.)

Comment: By "faster task" for periodic tasks it seems Simulink uses the frequency the task runs at rather than how long the task actually takes to run. That is not really the same thing as faster tasks having higher priority. 

In this case it is because a task which occurs less often has a tighter schedule with a higher penalty if it doesn't get done on time.

I think your answer is the correct one.